# JSF new website creation

Tags: session, jsf

I have a JSF project and I already have an `index.xhtml` page which is working fine. When I try to add another XHTML page, for some reason it is not connected to my session scoped managed bean. I add the code in my new page but it doesn't work like my `index.xhtml`. I even copy and pasted the code from index and it still does not work. Any thoughts?

Here is some of the code I have in my new page:

```
Amount: <h:inputText value="#{transactionBean.amount}" style="color: Yellow; background: Teal;"/>
Price <h:inputText value="#{transactionBean.pricePaid}" style="color: Yellow; background: Teal;"/
```

Here is my `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Please be specific. What "doesn't work"? Any errors in browser or server.log? No html rendered?

Comment: No no errors it doesn't show anything it doesn't display anything. Only the amount and price are shown to the page. There is no input text or anything else

Comment: Reason could be that the second page isn't processed by the faces servlet. What is in browser source?

Comment: Yes probably is that but how do i fix this?The url of the browser is showing "http://localhost:8080/SharePortfolioJSF/companies.xhtml"

Comment: I meant the html source in browser (right click --> view source). Maybe you have to adapt your faces servlet mapping in web.xml. Could you post the web.xml?

Comment: At the source is showing me exactly the code as i write it! The code at web.xml is:

Comment: That indicates that your page is not processed by the faces servlet.

Comment: how can i show you the web.xml code?Where should i write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mapped the faces servlet on `/faces/*` instead of `*.xhtml`. This means that you need to include `/faces` path in the URL to get the faces servlet to run.

So, you should not open the page by

> http://localhost:8080/SharePortfolioJSF/companies.xhtml

but instead by

> http://localhost:8080/SharePortfolioJSF/faces/companies.xhtml

Much better, however, is to just use `*.xhtml` as URL pattern of the faces servlet, so that you don't need to fiddle with virtual paths.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

*(note that your `<session-timeout>` of 30 minutes is the default already, just remove it)*

Answer (score 1):

From the comments:

Your second page isn't processed by the faces servlet. Your url pattern for the faces servlet is `/faces/*`. So all requests must contain the prefix `/faces` in order to get processed by the servlet.

It should work if you call your page with the following URL:

> http://localhost:8080/SharePortfolioJSF/faces/companies.xhtml